# What is the difference between REGEXP_CONTAINS and REGEXP_LIKE in N1QL?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

On the Couchbase documentation

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/patternmatchingfun.html

I saw that:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(expression, pattern)
Returns True if the string value contains the regular expression pattern.

REGEXP_LIKE(expression, pattern)
Returns True if the string value contains the regular expression pattern.
```

Is there any difference between this functions or one is an alias for another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

REGEXP_LIKE() requires that the expression exactly match the pattern. REGEXP_CONTAINS() is less restrictive; the expression only has to contain something that matches the pattern.

This query illustrates the difference. Note that the pattern being searched for is the *second* parameter to the function.

```
select REGEXP_CONTAINS("  foof  ", "foof") as contains, REGEXP_LIKE("  foof  ", "foof") as `like`

[
  {
    "contains": true,
    "like": false
  }
]
```